# Inserting Jypyter Lab code snippets in Beamer presentation

Tags: latex, jupyter-lab, beamer

Update:
I am trying to insert JupyterLab code snippet (with cell numbers and brackets [ ] showing In and Out) in a beamer presentation. This is my code.

```
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amssymb.sty\endcsname\empty
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsfonts.sty\endcsname\empty
\documentclass [10 pt]{beamer} 


\expandafter\let\csname ver@amssymb.sty\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname ver@amsfonts.sty\endcsname\relax

\usepackage{pgf, pgfpages, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{relsize} 
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Boadilla}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
\usecolortheme{orchid}
    \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
    \usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi

    \let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics

    \usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{nocaption}{}
    \captionsetup{format=nocaption,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

    \usepackage[Export]{adjustbox}
    \adjustboxset{max size={0.9\linewidth}{0.9\paperheight}}
    \usepackage{textcomp} 
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}
    }
    \usepackage{upquote} 
    \usepackage{eurosym} 
    \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} 
    \usepackage{fancyvrb} 
    \usepackage{grffile} 
    \makeatletter 
    \def\Gread@@xetex#1{
      \IfFileExists{"\Gin@base".bb}
      {\Gread@eps{\Gin@base.bb}}
      {\Gread@@xetex@aux#1}
    }
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{booktabs} 
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 

    \definecolor{ansi-black}{HTML}{3E424D}
    \definecolor{ansi-black-intense}{HTML}{282C36}
    \definecolor{ansi-red}{HTML}{E75C58}
    \definecolor{ansi-red-intense}{HTML}{B22B31}
    \definecolor{ansi-green}{HTML}{00A250}
    \definecolor{ansi-green-intense}{HTML}{007427}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow}{HTML}{DDB62B}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow-intense}{HTML}{B27D12}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue}{HTML}{208FFB}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue-intense}{HTML}{0065CA}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta}{HTML}{D160C4}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta-intense}{HTML}{A03196}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan}{HTML}{60C6C8}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan-intense}{HTML}{258F8F}
    \definecolor{ansi-white}{HTML}{C5C1B4}
    \definecolor{ansi-white-intense}{HTML}{A1A6B2}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-fg}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-bg}{HTML}{000000}

    \providecommand{\tightlist}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}

    \newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
    \newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}

    \newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}

    \def\br{\hspace*{\fill} \\* }
    \def\gt{>}
    \def\lt{<}
    \let\Oldtex\TeX
    \let\Oldlatex\LaTeX
    \renewcommand{\TeX}{\textrm{\Oldtex}}
    \renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\textrm{\Oldlatex}}

\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PY@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@fm\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vm\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sa\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@dl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ch\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cpf\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}

\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}

\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother

    \makeatletter
        \newbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox 
        \newbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedvisiblespace {\textcolor{red}{\textvisiblespace}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol {\textcolor{red}{\llap{\tiny$\m@th\hookrightarrow$}}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationindent {3ex } 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedafterbreak {\kern\Wrappedcontinuationindent\copy\Wrappedcontinuationbox} 

        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatspecials {% 
            \def\PYGZus{\discretionary{\char`\_}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\_}}% 
            \def\PYGZob{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\{}{\char`\{}}% 
            \def\PYGZcb{\discretionary{\char`\}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\}}}% 
            \def\PYGZca{\discretionary{\char`\^}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\^}}% 
            \def\PYGZam{\discretionary{\char`\&}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\&}}% 
            \def\PYGZlt{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\<}{\char`\<}}% 
            \def\PYGZgt{\discretionary{\char`\>}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\>}}% 
            \def\PYGZsh{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\#}{\char`\#}}% 
            \def\PYGZpc{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\%}{\char`\%}}% 
            \def\PYGZdl{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\$}{\char`\$}}% 
            \def\PYGZhy{\discretionary{\char`\-}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\-}}% 
            \def\PYGZsq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\textquotesingle}{\textquotesingle}}% 
            \def\PYGZdq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\"}{\char`\"}}% 
            \def\PYGZti{\discretionary{\char`\~}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\~}}% 
        } 

        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatpunct {% 
            \lccode`\~`\.\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\.}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\.}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\,\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\,}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\,}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\;\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\;}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\;}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\:\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\:}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\:}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\?\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\?}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\?}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\!\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\!}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\!}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\/\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\/}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\/}}}% 
            \catcode`\.\active
            \catcode`\,\active 
            \catcode`\;\active
            \catcode`\:\active
            \catcode`\?\active
            \catcode`\!\active
            \catcode`\/\active 
            \lccode`\~`\~   
        }
    \makeatother

    \let\OriginalVerbatim=\Verbatim
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\Verbatim}[1][1]{%

        \sbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox {\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol}%
        \sbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox {\FV@SetupFont\Wrappedvisiblespace}%
        \def\FancyVerbFormatLine ##1{\hsize\linewidth
            \vtop{\raggedright\hyphenpenalty\z@\exhyphenpenalty\z@
                \doublehyphendemerits\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
                \strut ##1\strut}%
        }%

        \def\FV@Space {%
            \nobreak\hskip\z@ plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font
            \discretionary{\copy\Wrappedvisiblespacebox}{\Wrappedafterbreak}
            {\kern\fontdimen2\font}%
        }%

        \Wrappedbreaksatspecials

        \OriginalVerbatim[#1,codes*=\Wrappedbreaksatpunct]%
    }
    \makeatother


    \definecolor{incolor}{HTML}{303F9F}
    \definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}
    \definecolor{cellborder}{HTML}{CFCFCF}
    \definecolor{cellbackground}{HTML}{F7F7F7}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\boxspacing}{\kern\kvtcb@left@rule\kern\kvtcb@boxsep}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\prompt}[4]{
        \ttfamily\llap{{\color{#2}[#3]:\hspace{3pt}#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }

}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\title[]{ \huge{\textbf{title}}}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
    {\insertshorttitle{}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
    {\insertshortsubtitle{}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}
    {\insertshortauthor{} \hspace*{1em}
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex} }
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\strokeifnotempty{%
\expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
\let\@next=\relax
\else
\let\@next=\pgfstroke
\fi
\@next%
}
\makeatother

\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{2 on 1 boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{10pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  }

\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 boxed}[letterpaper, border shrink=5mm]
  \nofiles
 }{}
}

\usepackage[TS1, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}% highly recommended with fontenc
\usepackage{mathptmx}


\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{frame}

\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\setcounter{framenumber}{0}


\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.84\textwidth,-.91cm)
\end{textblock*}
}

\begin{comment}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{comment}


\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{Sample frame title}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{n+nb}{print}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{l+s+s1}{This is a test}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{p}{)}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{Verbatim}
This is a test
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{ }{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

I am getting the following errors:

! Undefined control sequence.\boxspacing ->\kern \kvtcb@left@rule\kern \kvtcb @boxsep \prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}

! Missing number, treated as zero.@ ...is is a test}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{p}{)}

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].\PY #1#2->\PY @reset\PY @toks#1+\relax +\PY @do{#2} ...is is a test}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{p}{)}

! Undefined control sequence. \m \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\{}]

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: "a big load of errors" is not a really useful error description ... can you make a [mre] and include the .log file so we can have a look at this big load of errors?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: you are right; my bad. Just updated the question.

Comment: Please don't just post code fragments we would have to guess how to puzzle them together. Make a small document that reproduces the error you get

Comment: Just a guess: did you try with the `fragile` frame option?

Comment: Yes, I did and it didn't help. Still same errors

Comment: ..... so make a small document that actually reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` not necessary if your tex distribution was updated in the past couple of years
- `\usepackage{parskip}` not necessary, beamer does not indent paragraphs
- `\usepackage{graphicx}` not necessary, beamer loads this already
- `\usepackage{float} \floatplacement{figure}{H}` not necessary, beamer does not have a floating mechanism
- `\usepackage{xcolor}` not necessary, beamer loads this already
- `\usepackage{enumerate}` not necessary, beamer has it's own mechanism
- `\usepackage{geometry}`, `\usepackage{amsmath}`, `\usepackage{amssymb}` not necessary, beamer loads this already
- `\usepackage{hyperref}` not necessary, beamer loads this already
- `\usepackage{titling}` don't use this with beamer
- `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` don't use with beamer
- `\hypersetup{...}` don't do this. Beamer carefully sets up all the colours for the footline etc and this destroys the whole layout
- `\geometry{...}` don't do this. Beamer carefully sets up the pagelayout and this destroys it
- you must use the `\begin{frame}[fragile]` option if you have such fragile content

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


    \usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
%    \usepackage{parskip} % Stop auto-indenting (to mimic markdown behaviour)
    
    \usepackage{iftex}
    \ifPDFTeX
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \else
        \usepackage{fontspec}
    \fi

    % Basic figure setup, for now with no caption control since it's done
    % automatically by Pandoc (which extracts ![](path) syntax from Markdown).
%    \usepackage{graphicx}
    % Maintain compatibility with old templates. Remove in nbconvert 6.0
    \let\Oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
    % Ensure that by default, figures have no caption (until we provide a
    % proper Figure object with a Caption API and a way to capture that
    % in the conversion process - todo).
    \usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{nocaption}{}
    \captionsetup{format=nocaption,aboveskip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

    \usepackage[Export]{adjustbox} % Used to constrain images to a maximum size
    \adjustboxset{max size={0.9\linewidth}{0.9\paperheight}}
    \usepackage{float}
    \floatplacement{figure}{H} % forces figures to be placed at the correct location
%    \usepackage{xcolor} % Allow colors to be defined
%    \usepackage{enumerate} % Needed for markdown enumerations to work
%    \usepackage{geometry} % Used to adjust the document margins
%    \usepackage{amsmath} % Equations
%    \usepackage{amssymb} % Equations
    \usepackage{textcomp} % defines textquotesingle
    % Hack from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47451/13684:
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}% Upright quotes in Pygmentized code
    }
    \usepackage{upquote} % Upright quotes for verbatim code
    \usepackage{eurosym} % defines \euro
    \usepackage[mathletters]{ucs} % Extended unicode (utf-8) support
    \usepackage{fancyvrb} % verbatim replacement that allows latex
    \usepackage{grffile} % extends the file name processing of package graphics 
                         % to support a larger range
    \makeatletter % fix for grffile with XeLaTeX
    \def\Gread@@xetex#1{%
      \IfFileExists{"\Gin@base".bb}%
      {\Gread@eps{\Gin@base.bb}}%
      {\Gread@@xetex@aux#1}%
    }
    \makeatother

    % The hyperref package gives us a pdf with properly built
    % internal navigation ('pdf bookmarks' for the table of contents,
    % internal cross-reference links, web links for URLs, etc.)
%    \usepackage{hyperref}
    % The default LaTeX title has an obnoxious amount of whitespace. By default,
    % titling removes some of it. It also provides customization options.
%    \usepackage{titling}
    \usepackage{longtable} % longtable support required by pandoc >1.10
    \usepackage{booktabs}  % table support for pandoc > 1.12.2
%    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem} % IRkernel/repr support (it uses the enumerate* environment)
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % ulem is needed to support strikethroughs (\sout)
                                % normalem makes italics be italics, not underlines
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    

    
    % Colors for the hyperref package
    \definecolor{urlcolor}{rgb}{0,.145,.698}
    \definecolor{linkcolor}{rgb}{.71,0.21,0.01}
    \definecolor{citecolor}{rgb}{.12,.54,.11}

    % ANSI colors
    \definecolor{ansi-black}{HTML}{3E424D}
    \definecolor{ansi-black-intense}{HTML}{282C36}
    \definecolor{ansi-red}{HTML}{E75C58}
    \definecolor{ansi-red-intense}{HTML}{B22B31}
    \definecolor{ansi-green}{HTML}{00A250}
    \definecolor{ansi-green-intense}{HTML}{007427}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow}{HTML}{DDB62B}
    \definecolor{ansi-yellow-intense}{HTML}{B27D12}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue}{HTML}{208FFB}
    \definecolor{ansi-blue-intense}{HTML}{0065CA}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta}{HTML}{D160C4}
    \definecolor{ansi-magenta-intense}{HTML}{A03196}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan}{HTML}{60C6C8}
    \definecolor{ansi-cyan-intense}{HTML}{258F8F}
    \definecolor{ansi-white}{HTML}{C5C1B4}
    \definecolor{ansi-white-intense}{HTML}{A1A6B2}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-fg}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
    \definecolor{ansi-default-inverse-bg}{HTML}{000000}

    % commands and environments needed by pandoc snippets
    % extracted from the output of `pandoc -s`
    \providecommand{\tightlist}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
    % Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
    \newenvironment{Shaded}{}{}
    \newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.13,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.63,0.44}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.02,0.16,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}
    
    % Additional commands for more recent versions of Pandoc
    \newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.44,0.63}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{\textit{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.44,0.13}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
    \newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
    \newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{{#1}}}
    \newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    \newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.38,0.63,0.69}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
    
    
    % Define a nice break command that doesn't care if a line doesn't already
    % exist.
    \def\br{\hspace*{\fill} \\* }
    % Math Jax compatibility definitions
    \def\gt{>}
    \def\lt{<}
    \let\Oldtex\TeX
    \let\Oldlatex\LaTeX
    \renewcommand{\TeX}{\textrm{\Oldtex}}
    \renewcommand{\LaTeX}{\textrm{\Oldlatex}}
    % Document parameters
    % Document title
    \title{Untitled8}
    
    
    
    
    
% Pygments definitions
\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}

\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@w\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@k\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@o\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ow\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ne\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nv\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@no\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ni\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@na\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nt\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@nd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sd\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@si\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@se\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ss\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sx\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@m\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gh\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gu\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gd\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gr\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ge\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gs\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gp\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@go\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@gt\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@err\endcsname{\def\PY@bc##1{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kc\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kd\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kn\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@kr\endcsname{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@bp\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@fm\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vg\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@vm\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sa\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sc\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@dl\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s2\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@sh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@s1\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mb\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mf\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mh\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mi\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@il\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@mo\endcsname{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@ch\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cm\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cpf\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@c1\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\expandafter\def\csname PY@tok@cs\endcsname{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}

\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother


    % For linebreaks inside Verbatim environment from package fancyvrb. 
    \makeatletter
        \newbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox 
        \newbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedvisiblespace {\textcolor{red}{\textvisiblespace}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol {\textcolor{red}{\llap{\tiny$\m@th\hookrightarrow$}}} 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedcontinuationindent {3ex } 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedafterbreak {\kern\Wrappedcontinuationindent\copy\Wrappedcontinuationbox} 
        % Take advantage of the already applied Pygments mark-up to insert 
        % potential linebreaks for TeX processing. 
        %        {, <, #, %, $, ' and ": go to next line. 
        %        _, }, ^, &, >, - and ~: stay at end of broken line. 
        % Use of \textquotesingle for straight quote. 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatspecials {% 
            \def\PYGZus{\discretionary{\char`\_}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\_}}% 
            \def\PYGZob{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\{}{\char`\{}}% 
            \def\PYGZcb{\discretionary{\char`\}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\}}}% 
            \def\PYGZca{\discretionary{\char`\^}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\^}}% 
            \def\PYGZam{\discretionary{\char`\&}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\&}}% 
            \def\PYGZlt{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\<}{\char`\<}}% 
            \def\PYGZgt{\discretionary{\char`\>}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\>}}% 
            \def\PYGZsh{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\#}{\char`\#}}% 
            \def\PYGZpc{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\%}{\char`\%}}% 
            \def\PYGZdl{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\$}{\char`\$}}% 
            \def\PYGZhy{\discretionary{\char`\-}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\-}}% 
            \def\PYGZsq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\textquotesingle}{\textquotesingle}}% 
            \def\PYGZdq{\discretionary{}{\Wrappedafterbreak\char`\"}{\char`\"}}% 
            \def\PYGZti{\discretionary{\char`\~}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\char`\~}}% 
        } 
        % Some characters . , ; ? ! / are not pygmentized. 
        % This macro makes them "active" and they will insert potential linebreaks 
        \newcommand*\Wrappedbreaksatpunct {% 
            \lccode`\~`\.\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\.}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\.}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\,\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\,}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\,}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\;\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\;}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\;}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\:\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\:}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\:}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\?\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\?}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\?}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\!\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\!}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\!}}}% 
            \lccode`\~`\/\lowercase{\def~}{\discretionary{\hbox{\char`\/}}{\Wrappedafterbreak}{\hbox{\char`\/}}}% 
            \catcode`\.\active
            \catcode`\,\active 
            \catcode`\;\active
            \catcode`\:\active
            \catcode`\?\active
            \catcode`\!\active
            \catcode`\/\active 
            \lccode`\~`\~   
        }
    \makeatother

    \let\OriginalVerbatim=\Verbatim
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\Verbatim}[1][1]{%
        %\parskip\z@skip
        \sbox\Wrappedcontinuationbox {\Wrappedcontinuationsymbol}%
        \sbox\Wrappedvisiblespacebox {\FV@SetupFont\Wrappedvisiblespace}%
        \def\FancyVerbFormatLine ##1{\hsize\linewidth
            \vtop{\raggedright\hyphenpenalty\z@\exhyphenpenalty\z@
                \doublehyphendemerits\z@\finalhyphendemerits\z@
                \strut ##1\strut}%
        }%
        % If the linebreak is at a space, the latter will be displayed as visible
        % space at end of first line, and a continuation symbol starts next line.
        % Stretch/shrink are however usually zero for typewriter font.
        \def\FV@Space {%
            \nobreak\hskip\z@ plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font
            \discretionary{\copy\Wrappedvisiblespacebox}{\Wrappedafterbreak}
            {\kern\fontdimen2\font}%
        }%
        
        % Allow breaks at special characters using \PYG... macros.
        \Wrappedbreaksatspecials
        % Breaks at punctuation characters . , ; ? ! and / need catcode=\active     
        \OriginalVerbatim[#1,codes*=\Wrappedbreaksatpunct]%
    }
    \makeatother

    % Exact colors from NB
    \definecolor{incolor}{HTML}{303F9F}
    \definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}
    \definecolor{cellborder}{HTML}{CFCFCF}
    \definecolor{cellbackground}{HTML}{F7F7F7}
    
    % prompt
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\boxspacing}{\kern\kvtcb@left@rule\kern\kvtcb@boxsep}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\prompt}[4]{
        \ttfamily\llap{{\color{#2}[#3]:\hspace{3pt}#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
    }
    

    
    % Prevent overflowing lines due to hard-to-break entities
%    \sloppy 
    % Setup hyperref package
%    \hypersetup{
%      breaklinks=true,  % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
%      colorlinks=true,
%      urlcolor=urlcolor,
%      linkcolor=linkcolor,
%      citecolor=citecolor,
%      }
    % Slightly bigger margins than the latex defaults
    
%    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}


\title{Sample title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{n+nb}{print}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{l+s+s1}{This is a test}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{p}{)}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
This is a test
    \end{Verbatim}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{ }{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]

\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Your code works great. However, when I am adding the preamble to mine, I am getting the following errors:  ERROR 1: \kern\kvtcb@left@rule\kern\kvtcb@boxsep          ERROR 2: ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>@ \prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}      ERROR 3: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).<to be read again>@ \prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}         ERROR4: ! Undefined control sequence.\boxspacing ->\kern \kvtcb @left@rule\kern \kvtcb@boxsep \prompt{In}{incolor}{2}{\boxspacing}. Is there any hint you can provide me please?

Comment: @NNsr I asked you multiple times that you should provide the code that causes the error for you. I'm not going to guess what you might or might not have in this mysterious preamble you don't show!

Comment: My apologies; you are right; the only reason is that the preamble has got sloppier over time and I didn't want to cause unnecessary headache. I tried to post it as an update in the main question body; but it goes beyond the character limit...

Comment: I updated the code. I really appreciate if you help. Thank you